# Matrices in Python which have an alterable dimension

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, matrix

Firstly, I want to be able to specify a value, n, which results in a particular nxn matrix being produced:
To do this I used the code:

```
n = __

np.eye (n)
```

Which will produce the identity matrix of the specified dimension, n.
However, I do not want to create the identity matrix precisely. Instead, I want to create the nxn matrix with the following entries: (if n were 5)

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[a, b, c, 0, 0]
[0, a, b, c, 0]
[0, 0, a, b, c]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Can I use np.eye(n) and for loops as basis to solve my problem?

For example if I set n=4, I wish my code to form:

```
[1 , 0 , 0, 0]
[a , b, c, 0]
[0, a, b, c]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: It looks like there is a `1` missing in the richt lower corner of your 5x5 matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `np.eye` and then a for loop to set all the values.

```
In [30]: a, b, c = (5, 6, 7)
In [31]: n = 5
In [32]: arr = np.eye(n)
In [33]: for i in range(1, n-1):
    ...:     arr[i, i-1: i+2] = (a, b, c)
    ...:     

In [34]: arr
Out[34]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Here we are creating an identity matrix of size `n`. Then in line 33 we loop over the rows (excluding the first and last row) of the matrix and replace the corresponding values in that row with `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you please explain the lines 33?

Comment: You're a hero. My uni lecturers were on strike for 4 weeks and we had to self teach. The stress was really high lately and was getting very muddled. :)